# C# For each line do this:

Tags: foreach, background

I have a background task doing a task, so my GUI doesn't freeze up.

The code is:

```
   private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork_1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int index = 0; index < this.combos.Length; ++index)
        {

            string[] strArray = Strings.Split(this.combos[index], ":", -1, CompareMethod.Binary);
            string username = strArray[0];
            string pass = strArray[1];
            //do stuff
```

and it does a task. The problem is, it only does the task for 1 line of text that is loaded, then it stops. I need to to continue for every line of code.
For instance, I user loads up their order numbers and wants to retrieve the status of every single on. The task is working fine when they press start, but only retrieves status for 1 code, not all of them.

This is how I call it:

```
    private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: could you post the part of the code that calls your backgroundWorker1_DoWork_1 ?

Comment: Edited it to contain the button that starts it.

Comment: what do you mean that it does the task for 1 line of text? did you wanted to keep running this thread forever or something like that? i'm sorry but you should explain what you want to achieve and where's the problem exactly

Comment: Alright, I added the problem in more details, for those who don't understand.